# Need some ideas on how to let the user choose level pack, then a particular level on a mobile platform

Tags: mobile, graphics

For an Android application, the user is to select a group of levels, and then a particular level within that group. The phone orientation is to be held in landscape (e.g. sideways). What do you think is the "best" way to present these choices to the user?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is this about a game? If so, what kind of game? Also, don't ask for "best" ways; try to define what best is for you, eg. most usable, most popular, most often encountered, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the classic grid layout that many early games used and is still used today in agrybirds. There is a linier grid of levels and when you select the level it opens a grid of all the levels in that group.

Here is the angry birds example from chrome: (and please no making fun of my star ratings, this was my first experience with angry birds)
[image: Level Groups]
[image: Grid Layout of levels]

Its very straight forward but most importantly its also easy to use on a mobile touch interface.

Comment: I definitely looked at Angry Birds, because it is the pinnacle of Android gaming UI. What inhibits me from following their paradigm is (1) lack of graphic design prowess, (2) don't want to be a copy cat (people would know). It is a remarkable design but I'm just not capable of producing something on that level. I think I'm going to go for parallel lists, and try to deck them out using the Android API. Nice website BTW. Any interest getting on board with a game to be released on the Android Market in about 2 months? Thanks for the input.

Comment: Its a standard at this point, really. It was done LOOONG before angry birds on nintendo games and such. I dont think it takes much design whatsoever. Just a grid of levels.

Comment: You're probably right. Icon > list. I guess I'll take the animation route as to not produce a poor man's Angry Birds.